# How can I write an angularjs filter to search for string fragments/sequences of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, search, filter

I'm trying to write an angularjs custom filter that checks whether an array of countries contains a search string entered by the user.

The string can consist of one letter (e.g. 'E'), or a fragment of n-letters (e.g. 'lan') or an entire word (e.g. 'England').

In every case, all countries containing that one letter or that fragment should be returned, so 'E' would return 'England', 'Estonia' etc. while 'lan' would return 'England', 'Ireland', etc.

So far my filter returns the entire country or single letters but I'm having difficulty with string fragments:

1. HTML Template:

   ```
   <input ng-model="filter.text" type="search" placeholder="Filter..."/>

   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data | listfilter:filter.text">
   </ul>
   ```
2. angularJS

   ```
   angular.module('sgComponents').filter('listfilter',[ function () {
   return function(items, searchText) {
       var filtered = [];            

       angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
           if(item.label === searchText) { // matches whole word, e.g. 'England'
               filtered.push(item);
           }
           var letters = item.label.split('');
           _.each(letters, function(letter) {
               if (letter === searchText) { // matches single letter, e.g. 'E'
                   console.log('pushing');
                   filtered.push(item);
               }
           });
           // code to match letter fragments, e.g. 'lan'
       });
       return filtered;
   };
   }]);
   ```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is much simpler than that, use the `String.indexOf()` function:

```
angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
    if( item.label.indexOf(searchText) >= 0 ) filtered.push(item);
});
```

You may want to turn both strings `.toLowerCase()` to do case-insensitive matching:

```
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
    if( item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) >= 0 ) filtered.push(item);
});
```

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot. I needed to do this as you recommend: if(    item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ) filtered.push(item);

Answer (score 7):

```
angular.module('sgComponents').filter('listfilter',[ function () {
    return function(items, searchText) {
        var filtered = []; 
        var regex = new RegExp(".*" + searchItem + ".*", "ig");
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if(regex.test(item)){
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Don't do that: it's very slow. Please at least move `var regex = new RegExp(".*" + searchItem + ".*", "ig")` before the loop. However better approach is to use `indexOf` instead RegExp.

Comment: thanks for the response. Nikos' indexOf() solution proved the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Angular-UI-Bootstrap directive for `typeahead` it does exactly what you want: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately I'm not using angular-ui

Comment: FWIW, angular-ui isn't a development framework like jquery-ui that you have to be 'using'. It's a kit of parts you can deploy as-needed, without needing to otherwise modify your app.