# Filter an array of objects by a property containing a substring in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Let's say i have an array like:

```
array = [{
    title: "foo1",
    content: "bar1"
},{
    title: "foo2",
    content: "bar2"
},{
    title: "foo3",
    content: "bar3"
}];
```

Now i want to filter this array to have the objects that their title **contains** a character like '3'.
So now my filtered array should be

```
filteredArray = [{
    title:"foo3",
    content: "bar3"
}];
```

I've tried

```
    filteredArray = $filter('filter')(array, {
        title: "foo3"
    });
```

But the problem with this is that title needs to be exactly "foo3". if i put "3" it won't filter that because it doesn't check if it contains it, it looks for an exact match.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filter filter (yeah, I know) does a contains filtering...

I pasted your code (working) into [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/wdGXcFtCbMOavMkePiI1?p=preview) and filtered on `3` and got back the title: 'foo3' element

```
array = [{
  title: "foo1",
  content: "bar1"
},{
  title: "foo2",
  content: "bar2"
},{
  title: "foo3",
  content: "bar3"
}];

$scope.filteredData = $filter('filter')(array, {
  title: "3",
});
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, I don't know how i missed it. It's working as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write your own filter. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405346/how-can-i-write-an-angularjs-filter-to-search-for-string-fragments-sequences-of) on how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you, the link did help but thanks to @Brocco realized $filter (filter) does a containing filtering. So no need to write your own filter.