# ng-show working with multiple filters in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have an ng-repeat list with multiple filters, but as I need the elements to be **hidden and not removed from the DOM**, I use ng-show for the filtering.

This is how my first filter look like:

```
<a href="" ng-click="myFilter = ''; toggle = toggle=0; togglesec=0; mySecondFilter = {}" ng-class="{'active' : toggle==0}" >
   Tot
</a>

<a href="" ng-click="myFilter = 'pa'; toggle = toggle=1;  togglesec=0;  mySecondFilter = {}" ng-class="{'active' : toggle==1}">
   Pa
</a>

<a href="" ng-click="myFilter = 'Reposteria'; toggle = toggle=2; togglesec=0; mySecondFilter = {}" ng-class="{'active' : toggle==2}">
   Reposteria
</a>
```

And the second one:

```
<div ng-init="togglesec=0; mySecondFilter = {}">
   <a ng-click="mySecondFilter = {}; togglesec = togglesec=0" ng-class="{'active' : togglesec==0}">
       All
   </a>
   <a ng-click="mySecondFilter = {'vegan': true}; togglesec = togglesec=1" ng-class="{'active' : togglesec==1}">
       Vegan
   </a>
   <a ng-click="mySecondFilter = {'gluten': true}; togglesec = togglesec=2" ng-class="{'active' : togglesec==2}">
       Gluten Free
   </a>
</div>
```

Now, I was able to filter the ng-repeat using ng-show and the first filter like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="pa in products" ng-show="pa.tipus.indexOf(myFilter) != -1">
```

Basically it compares the value of **myFilter** with the **pa.tipus** object property, and it works OK.

But it won't work with the second filter, because mySecondFilter is an object, not a string (it needs to filter the results containing **vegan:true** or **gluten:true**)

Here's an example of my object type:

```
pa {
    tipus : 'pa',
    gluten : false,
    vegan : true
}
```

Any tips on how to combine both filters in the same ng-show?

### EDIT

I've applied the answer by Naren, but I get the following error on click on any filter:

```
angular.min.js:122 TypeError: Cannot create property 'vegan' on string ''.
```

I've also tried to initialize myFilter by adding this, but no luck, same error appears:

```
$scope.myFilter = {
  tipus : '',
  vegan : '',
  gluten : '',
  lactosa : ''
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Since the user wanted a generic version for the filtering. The following function should be the answer.

```
$scope.validate = function(row) {
    for (var key in $scope.myFilter) {
      if ($filter('filter')([row], {
          [key]: $scope.myFilter[key]
        }).length === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Where we loop through an object where all the filters are stored, then return false if any of the filters are not satisfied.

Please check the below example to get a understanding of how the filter works.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**Old:**

Here is my version of the fix. Angular's `$filter` will be great for identifying the object with the property, but this is not possible to have written in the HTML, hence I call a function which will return true or false to the `ng-show`.

```
  $scope.validate = function(row) {
    if (row.tipus.indexOf($scope.myFilter) != -1) {
      if ($filter('filter')([row], $scope.mySecondFilter).length !== 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Let me explain the function. First we receive the row of the `ng-repeat` through the parameter of validate, after which I apply the first `if` condition which is basically whatever you had written earlier, this code works great btw. Then I check the row using the `$filter` syntax for the object present in `$scope.mySecondFilter`, Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225507/filter-an-array-of-objects-by-a-property-containing-a-substring-in-angularjs) for more on filtering with `$filter`, this will basically check if the row passed contains the required object property and return `true` or `false`.

Here is a working example of your code for reference.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Please let me know if this fixes your issue completely :)

Comment: It works! How could I include a third filter or fourth filter like the second one?

Comment: @EricMitjans Please mention you want a generic solution in the question! I updated my answer, please use this code as a template and build your application.

Comment: @EricMitjans Did this generic solution solve your issue completely? Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: @EricMitjans The code works, let me know when we can do a JSFiddle collaborate where you can show me the error!