# Angular filter object map

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have one input field and and object map to give filtered options from datalist

```
<datalist id="fromStationList">
<select id="fromStationSelectList">  
<option ng-repeat="(LocObject, locValue) in filterCityList()">{{locValue.cityName}}</option>
</select>
</datalist>

<input  list="fromStationList" type="search" ng-model="fromLocation" class="input-text full-width"/>
```

---Script ---

```
// it is an json object recieved from ajax call
$scope.locationsMap = "{"PNQ":{"id":"PNQ","cityName":"Pune"},"BLR":{"id":"BLR","cityName":"Bengaluru"},"DEL":{"id":"DEL","cityName":"Delhi"},"AGC":{"id":"AGC","cityName":"Agra"}}"

$scope.filterCityList = function() {
var result = {};
if($scope.fromLocation == undefined)
    return $scope.locationsMap;
var enteredKeywords = ('' + $scope.fromLocation).toLowerCase();

angular.forEach($scope.locationsMap, function(value, key) {
     var cityValue = ('' + value.cityName).toLowerCase();
    if ((cityValue).indexOf(enteredKeywords) > -1) {
        result[key] = value;
    }
});

return result;
```

}

But it is filtering only when i enter the first letter for ex. on entering "p" it suggests Pune, but on entering "g" it doesnt suggest agra or bengaluru.

Comment: Angular provides built in filter options when using an ng-repeat. Example:
ng-repeat="(LocObject, locValue) in locationsMap | filter: fromLocation

Comment: can u please make a working fiddle of your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I write an angularjs filter to search for string fragments/sequences of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405346/how-can-i-write-an-angularjs-filter-to-search-for-string-fragments-sequences-of)

Comment: ng-repeat="(LocObject, locValue) in locationsMap | filter: fromLocation works when locationsMap  is a array not an object map.

Comment: JS fiddle for this:- http://jsfiddle.net/awnqm/282/